# Результат тернарного оператора в Groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter, тернарный-оператор

Использую JMeter для тестирования API.
Использую JSR223 Assertion Groovy 2.4.13
Скрипт

```
import groovy.json.*
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = jsonSlurper.parseText(vars.get("generalInfo"))
assert json instanceof Map
vars.put("json", "" + json)

def json2 = vars.get("generalInfo") != [] ? {jsonSlurper.parseText(vars.get("generalInfo")); assert json2 instanceof Map} : null
vars.put("json2", "" + json2)
```

Результат первого преобразования(корректный для меня)

```
json=
[
:   masterId:5A3D6E28-5536-4E3A-856C-38AD26011DC9, 
:   ....
:   personalInfo:
:   [
:   ...
:   ], 
:   ...
:]
```

Результат второго преобразования

```
json2=Script2388$_run_closure1@766d1c19
```

Вопрос: почему тернарный оператор возвращает другой результат?

Как правильно было бы использовать его, если мне нужно проверить что в vars есть не пустой массив и распарсить его.

так же пробовал

```
def json2 = vars.get("generalInfo") != [] ? {json2 = jsonSlurper.parseText(vars.get("generalInfo")); 
assert json2 instanceof Map} : null
```

Comment: так же пробовал 
`def json2 = vars.get("generalInfo") != [] ? {json2 = jsonSlurper.parseText(vars.get("generalInfo")); assert json2 instanceof Map} : null`